# Simplest Unhalvable Shape

Tags: general-topology, recreational-mathematics, 3d, solid-geometry

Consider a connected 3D-printable shape such as the below. It appears that any plane passing through the centroid will divide the shape into more than two pieces.  Define a shape with this property *unhalvable*.

[image]

Would the simplest unhalvable shape be topologically equivalent to a sphere, a torus, or something else?

What are some simple unhalvable shapes?

Is the below embedding of the Trefoil knot unhalvable?

[image]

Comment: I'd venture that it would be a sphere. Take a shape like the one you have above in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (which is topologically equivalent to a torus) and cut it somewhere. I guess that it's still "unhalvable", but is now topologically equivalent to a sphere, right? One example of an unhalvable shape which I can think of is the co-ordinate axis in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: A closely related problem has been studied for knots: A point $p$ is in the *second hull* of a knot (realized as an embedded curve in $\Bbb R^3$) if every plane through $p$ intersects the knot in at least four points. In particular, the trefoil knot admits an embedding for which the second hull contains the centroid. This question asks about solids, rather than embedded curves, but I'd guess some of the results for knots can be applied here by thickening knots by a small amount. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204106.pdf for more, esp. the figure on p. 1.

Comment: Travis, post a link to your paper as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd venture that it would be a sphere. Take a shape like the one you have above in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (which is topologically equivalent to a torus) and cut it somewhere. I guess that it's still "unhalvable", but is now topologically equivalent to a sphere.

One example of an unhalvable shape which I can think of is the co-ordinate axis in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Whether the trefoil knot is unhalvable would seem to depend on how you embed it in $\mathbb{R}^3$ - because that would change where your plane intersects it. You probably would need to define "unhalvable" a little more rigorously to ask questions like that.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why is a sphere unhalvable?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I don't say that a sphere is in general unhalvable.

Comment: Oh I'm an idiot, ignore me (lol)